# console.log returning undefined in for loop

Tags: javascript

i'm looping through an array of 3 buttons
inside the for loop i have attached event Listener to each button
i'm trying to console.log the button i'm currently looping through but it returns undefined.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(buttons[i]);
    // returns undefined
  })
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>a</button>
<button class='btn'>b</button>
<button class='btn'>c</button>
```

Comment: By the time your handler is called, `i` is set to `buttons.length`. Using `for (let i...` is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closure to achieve it.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (let i = 0, ln = buttons.length; i < ln; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    buttons[index].addEventListener('click' , function() {
            console.log(buttons[index]);
            // returns undefined
    })
  })(i)
}
```

```html
<button class='btn'>a</button>
<button class='btn'>b</button>
<button class='btn'>c</button>
```

Comment: Using `let` is the simplest way to create scoped variables. See my comment.

Comment: could you please explain why we had to create an i variable and doing it all  inside a function ?

Comment: @AfaqQazi Because by the time your callback is executed, `i` will have been incremented past the end of `buttons.length`. The duplicate question explains this in detail.

Comment: @AfaqQazi, I changed a bit my post.
You can create a variable and assign that var a value of the current `i` or passing i as a params of the closure function.

Comment: This would make total sense if you was trying to keep with `ES5`, but your first line is a `let`, so that's broke that rule.  And currently you are creating a global variable called `i`, yes the OP did this too, but if you can use let, the functional scoping is overkill.

Comment: Actually, the best thing would have been not to answer the question at all (delete) since it was pretty clear this had been asked before. If OP has a specific concern after reading the linked question, they should post that question. This is why gave a quick summary as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I post my answer the same time as it was marked dup.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina But I'm sure you knew this had been asked before. This is JS interview 101.